# How to call testcase class inside other testcase class?

Tags: android, junit

I have problem with creating JUnit Test Automation.

My project has many activities (some activities inside other activities).
So I create testcase for each activity. But the problem how can i call a testcase inside other testcases (like activity inside other activities).

Can any one give me some idear?

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

You tests should live in a different project not with your Activities.
Then the test runner, usually [InstrumentationTestRunner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestRunner.html), will be able to discover and run your test cases using instrospection.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: this can get very, very messy.  If you need one test case to spawn another test case, there's probably a better way of doing it.*

JUnit operates on classes.  If you want to create tests at runtime, you have to create classes at runtime.  Here, the method `specializedTester` creates an anonymous subclass where `getInstance()` returns specialized Activity objects for testing.

```
public abstract class ActivityTestCase extends TestCase {

    public abstract Activity getInstance();

    public static Class specializedTester(final String specialty) {
        return new ActivityTestCase() {
            public Activity getInstance() {
                return new Activity(specialty);
            }
        };
    }

    public void testChildActivities() {
        Activity activity = getInstance();
        for(Activity a : activity.children()) {
            // "check ripeness", "bargain hunt", "check out", etc
            Class c = specializedTester(a.specialty);
            suite.addTestSuite(c);
        }
    }

    static TestSuite suite;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        suite = new TestSuite(ActivityTestCase.specializedTester("buy groceries"));
        TestRunner.run(suite);
    }
}
```